# Como puedo escribir esta "sobrecarga de clase" en Java

Tags: java, c#, clase, genericos, sobrecarga

Tengo escrito en c# este par de clases de ejemplo

```
public class Foo<T> 
{

}
```

y esta otra

```
public class Foo
{

}
```

a modo de "sobrecarga de clase" (no sé si sea correcto decirlo de esta manera) y compilan correctamente. 
Lo que quiero es hacer este mismo par de clases en Java, pero al momento de hacerlo tengo el error de "**Clase duplicada**".
Entonces la pregunta es si es posible hacer esto en Java de alguna manera o deberia plantearlo de otro manera?

Comment: En Java es la misma clase, en un caso estás declarandola clase con un un Tipo parametrizado (Generic) y en el otro no.

Comment: En realidad en c# son dos clases totalmente distintas, no hay sobrecarga. Lo que pasa es que c# tiene mejor manejo de genéricos que java.